# xargs: Does order of options matter?

Tags: xargs

## Input 0

```
echo foo | xargs -L 1 -I '{}' echo '{}'
```

## Output 0

```
foo
```

## Input 1

```
echo foo | xargs -I '{}' -L 1 echo '{}'
```

## Output 1

```
{} foo
```

Why changing the order of options of xargs changes the output?

Version: `xargs (GNU findutils) 4.6.0`

Comment: Also cannot replicate this on the Mac BSD...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When options given to xargs conflict, order may matter.

[IEEE Std 1003.1-2008, 2016 Edition/Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) added the following text<sup>1</sup> to the specification of xargs:

> The **-I**, **-L**, and **-n** options are mutually-exclusive. Some implementations use the last one specified if more than one is given on a command line; other implementations treat combinations of the options in different ways.

This codifies the behavior of many implementations of xargs, going back to the original version in PWB/Unix, whose [man page](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=PWB1/usr/man/man1/xargs.1) says

> When there are flag conflicts (e.g., **-l** vs. **-n**), the last flag has precedence.

In the GNU version of xargs, `-L` disables any previous `-I` option. So in your second example,

```
echo foo | xargs -I '{}' -L 1 echo '{}'
```

`{}` is just an ordinary argument passed to `echo`, with no substitution being done.

<sup>[1]</sup>Compared to [IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition/Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xargs.html).

Comment: You are **awesome**. Let's have a further discussion then. I don't really understand why `-I` has to conflict against `-n`. It seems `-I` is the only way of putting the argument in the middle of the command (instead of appending it at the last). But what if the user wants at most 1 argument for each command (`-n 1`) at the same time? Then he has to write `-I {} -n 1` or `-n 1 -I {}` but both are invalid. Why `xargs` has to have this limitation?

Comment: @Cyker, `-I` changes the way the input is read (one arg per line with leading but not trailing blanks removed, and quoting still understood) and uses one arg at a time anyway so `-n 1` would be redundant. `-I` with GNU `xargs` works in combination with `-d` or `-0` which is all what matters there. Compare `printf ' a b\nc d \n' | xargs -n1 sh -c 'IFS=,; printf "<%s>\n" "$*"' sh {}` with the same with `-L1` instead of `-n1` and with `-I {}` and with `-d '\n' -I {}`

Comment: `xargs -I {} cmd {}` is not the same as `xargs -L1 cmd`. In the latter case, the words on each line make up separate arguments to `cmd`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yeah, I mentioned the `-I` implies  `-L 1` bit because it says so on the GNU man page, but now I see that it's wrong. I'll remove my comment and reword it.

Comment: @Cyker Going back to the original version of xargs 40 years ago, if you gave it `-i`, it used complete lines as input and ignored any `-n` option. I don't know why they chose to do this, but I'd guess the major use case for `xargs -i` was to process lists of filenames, one per line, such as the output of `find`. Nowadays, you could use the shell `for` command and shell variables to loop over files, using either the output of find `$(find ...)` or globs. The PWB/Unix shell did not have a `for` command.