# Why does `xargs -n ` on SmartOS (SunOS) behave differently than other implementations?

Tags: solaris, xargs, gnu

It seems the `-n` option on the xargs found in SmartOS (and I assume Solaris) does not behave like any other version of xargs I've encountered.

Take this example:

Builtin /usr/bin/xargs (odd behavoir):

```
# printf 'one\0two\0three' | xargs -0 -I{} -n 1 echo "- {}"
- {} one
- {} two
- {} three
```

GNU Findutils /opt/local/bin/xargs (expected behavoir):

```
# printf 'one\0two\0three' | /opt/local/bin/xargs -0 -I{} -n 1 echo "- {}"
- one
- two
- three
```

Xargs from MacOS, NetBSD, and CentOS all behave the same as the last example. What's different about the SmartOS xargs?

From the SmartOS xargs manpage:

```
   -n number
                  Invokes utility using as many standard input arguments
                  as possible, up to number (a positive decimal integer)
                  arguments maximum. Fewer arguments are used if:

                      o      The command line length accumulated exceeds
                             the size specified by the -s option (or
                             {LINE_MAX} if there is no -s option), or

                      o      The last iteration has fewer than number, but
                             not zero, operands remaining.
```

From the Gnu Findutils xargs manpage:

```
   -n max-args, --max-args=max-args
          Use at most max-args arguments per command line.  Fewer than max-args arguments will be used if the size (see the -s option) is  exceeded,  un‐
          less the -x option is given, in which case xargs will exit.
```

I discovered this difference while porting a shell script and I'm curious if anyone knows why the behavoir is different.

Comment: Looks like it's the `-I` that's behaving differently (not doing anything on SnartOS), not the `-n`.

Comment: That was my thought as well, but if I remove `-n 1` it works as expected. I've tried other characters besides ``{}`` as well as the ``-i`` flag which assumes ``{}`` I won't rule out the ``-I`` but I don't know how else to try it.

Comment: What happens with those other placeholders?

Comment: If you want to see that GNU xargs behavior is not always the one expected, try this `printf 'one\0two\0three\0four' | gxargs -0 -I{} -n 2 echo "- {}"` ;-)

Comment: I'm surprised that `-0` worked with the OS-supplied `xargs`.  `-0` is a non-standard GNU extension to `xargs`.  It's not a [POSIX-standard option.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot combine the `-I` and `-n` options. That's what the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) says:

> The `-I`, `-L`, and `-n` options are mutually-exclusive. Some
>        implementations use the last one specified if more than one is given
>        on a command line; other implementations treat combinations of the
>        options in different ways.

See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388018/308316) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/466266/308316).

Comment: Your answer would be more complete by indicating which are the correct arguments that should be used in this particular case... Should the `-n` or the `-I` be dropped, and why?

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger I guess the OP's example was only to illustrate the broken buggy behavior; I've already explained in the linked answer how to insert arguments in the xargs' command at any position without the use of `-I`. I will not repeat it here, since that wasn't the point of the question.